# Random variable independent of $\sigma$-algebra and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

What does it mean to say that a random variable is independent of a sigma-algebra, and why then does this imply that $E(RV|  \sigma) = RV$?. I have no clue what this independence stuff is about (couldn't find it using google either), and surely $E(RV|  \sigma) = RV$ seems like the logical **definition** of it?

Answer (score 9):

A random variable $X$ is independent of a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ if the $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent. Recall that $\sigma(X)$ consists of all sets of the form $\{X\in B\}$, where $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

If $X$ has finite expectation and is independent of $\mathcal{G}$, then in fact
$$ \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]=\mathbb{E}[X]$$
On the other hand, if $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable (and has finite expectation) then
$$ \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]=X $$

This fits with the intuitive description of conditional expectation as an average based on the information contained in $\mathcal{G}$.

Answer (score 6):

As @carmichael561 remarks, independence between random variable $X$ and sigma-algebra $\cal G$ amounts to the assertion
$$
P(X\in B\mid A)=P(X\in B)\tag1$$
for every Borel $B$ and every $A\in\cal G$. In particular it implies
$$
E(X\mid A)=E(X).\tag2
$$
for every $A\in\cal G$. Regarding your question whether (2) can serve as the *definition*, the answer is that (2) is not equivalent to (1). It can be proved that condition (1) implies the desirable property
$$
E(h(X)\mid A) = E(h(X))\tag3
$$
for all functions $h$ (assuming $h$ measurable and $h(X)$ integrable), but you can't get to (3) from (2) alone.

Here's an example where (2) does not imply (1). On the four-point set $\Omega=\{a,b,c,d\}$ let $P$ put mass $\frac12$ on the set $A:=\{a\}$ and mass $\frac16$ on the remaining three singletons. Define $X$ by $X(a)=X(b)=0$, $X(c)=1$, $X(d)=-1$. Take $\cal G$ to be the sigma-algebra generated by set $A$. You can check that $X$ satisfies condition (2) for every set in $\cal G$. However, $P(X=0\mid A)=1\ne \frac23=P(X=0)$, so condition (1) is not satisfied. Moreover, $E(X^2\mid A)=0\ne \frac13=E(X^2)$, so condition (3) is not satisfied.